# Can I get notified when friends check-in nearby on Foursquare?

Tags: foursquare

Is there a way for me to set up notifications (e.g. iPhone push notifications, or email) when a Foursquare friend checks in nearby? Currently it looks like [I can turn on notifications for all check-ins](https://foursquare.com/settings/notifications), but I can't restrict them to check-ins near my last one:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Now that the check-ins are in Swarm and not in Foursquare there is a way to set notifications only for the nearby check-ins. At least according to the [official documentation](https://support.foursquare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202840110-Notifications-in-Swarm).